# Default django auth schema doesn't create reference between users and groups

Tags: python, django, sqlite, database-design, django-models

I am learning django with the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/).

I've configured the settings.py to use SQLite, 
and ran `python manage.py syncdb`.
The following schema was generated, and upon viewing the schema, I found that there isn't a reference between `auth_user` table's `id` column and `auth_user_groups` table's `user_id` column. However, there *did* exist a reference between `auth_group` table's `id` column and `auth_user_groups` table's `group_id` column.

Why isn't there a reference between auth_user table and auth_group table?

```
--..OTHER TABLES
    CREATE TABLE "auth_user" (
        "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        "username" varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
        "email" varchar(75) NOT NULL,
        "password" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        "is_staff" bool NOT NULL,
        "is_active" bool NOT NULL,
        "is_superuser" bool NOT NULL,
        "last_login" datetime NOT NULL,
        "date_joined" datetime NOT NULL
    );
    CREATE TABLE "auth_user_groups" (
        "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        "user_id" integer NOT NULL, --why not "user_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id") ?
        "group_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_group" ("id"),
        UNIQUE ("user_id", "group_id")
--...OTHER TABLES
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLite [recommends using the `REFERENCES` syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html), and full FOREIGN KEY support requires an extra pragma switch.

Historically, SQLite did not support FOREIGN KEY constraints at all, and when they were added it was with an explicit per-connection switch to turn this on to retain backwards compatibility. For Django, using `REFERENCES` suffices, does not limit Django to the more recent versions and saves having to enable the FOREIGN KEY support or detecting that the feature has been compiled in.

Comment: I didn't know that REFERENCES and FOREIGN KEY are not the same thing. However, why did django create `"user_id" integer NOT NULL`, instead of `"user_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id")` in `auth_user_groups` table's definition?

Comment: Ah, *that* I don't know without a lot more spelunking. I may or may not have time for that today.